# Clarification on CursorLoader and LoaderManager android

Tags: android

Good day, I have a class that implements the LoaderCallbacks, and hence have the unimplemented methods overriden. onCreateLoader(),onLoaderFinshed() and onLoaderReset();

in the Activity onCreate(), i prepare a loader:

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

and in the onCreateLoader(), i have returned a custom loader class here which extends the SimpleLoader class by christain.

Now just wondering, if i do this somewhere in my class outside of the onCreateLoader() method:

```
CursorLoader loader = new cursorLoader(
this,android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null,null);
loader.loadInBackground();
//cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
```

Does the LoaderCallback hold a reference to it and calls onLoadFinished() or is this a different implementation altogether. what does this really mean?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new CursorLoader has nothing to do with the LoaderManager.

Then the `onLoadFinished()` method will **not** be called when creating a new CursorLoader.

### What if the data changes:

If the data monitored by the Loader changes, the Loader will requery itself. But the `onLoadFinished()` will not be called if this Loader hasn't been supplied to the LoaderManager by the `onCreateLoader` method.

### To summarise:

Imagine you, or some else process, modify the data you're monitoring by a Loader.

If this Loader **has been** supplied to the LoaderManager by the `onCreateLoader` then  `onLoadFinished()` will be called.

If this Loader **hasn't been** supplied to the LoaderManager by the `onCreateLoader` then  `onLoadFinished()` will **not** be called.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Since it does not call the onLoadfinished(). does that mean one can just used the result straight. what i mean is, i can do this cursor = loader.loadInBackground() and use it directly with no cost?

Comment: The method "loadInBackground" is supposed to be called on a worker thread, not on the UI thread. You may want to read the source code of the method (with eclipse attached sources or here : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/android/content/CursorLoader.java#CursorLoader.loadInBackground%28%29 ) to see exactly what it does. As you can read, the method is just making a regular query which is not asynchronous. Then you can use it "straight" as you said, but you should be aware it is not the way it is supposed to be used.

Comment: You can try using an AsyncQueryHandler instead (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.html) to make an asynchronous query that won't block the UI thread.